# gcloud command not found in google cloud Functions Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-shell

I want to user gcloud command in cloud Functions source

main.py

```
import os
command = 'gcloud --project {}~~'

os.system(command)
```

but erorr

```
sh: 1: gcloud: not found
```

Comment: There is no `gcloud` in CF. You may need to use the libraries of the product you wish to interact with

Answer (score 1):

As @puteri said You may need to use the libraries of the product you wish to interact with.
So, Can you install this [Python Client](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudfunctions/latest) for Cloud Functions and also refer to this multiple Python Cloud [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference) . Post installing this python client that may help in resolving your issue.

Also, gcloud command not found error occurs if your installation is unsuccessful due to the find command not being recognized find this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55373753/19230181) . You can Try another alternate way to  resolve this issue by installing the [cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk#:%7E:text=Google%20Cloud%20SDK%3A%20Tools%20for,directly%20in%20the%20web%2Dbrowser.)